# Rule out solutions in pyomo

Tags: pyomo

New to pyomo and python in general and I am trying to implement a simple solution to a binary integer programming problem. However the problem is large but a large percentage of the values of the matrix x are known in advance. I have been trying to figure out how to 'tell' pyomo that some values are known in advance and what they are.

```
from __future__ import division # converts to float before division
from pyomo.environ import * # Make symbolds used by pyomo known to python

model = AbstractModel() # Declaration of an abstract model, called model

model.users = Set()
model.slots = Set()

model.prices=Param(model.users, model.slots)
model.users_balance=Param(model.users)
model.slot_bounds=Param(model.slots)

model.x = Var(model.users, model.slots, domain=Binary)

# Define the objective function
def obj_expression(model):
    return sum(sum(model.prices[i,j] * model.x[i,j] for i in model.users) 
for j in model.slots)

model.OBJ = Objective(rule=obj_expression, sense=maximize) 

# A user can only be assigned to one slot
def one_slot_rule(model, users):
    return sum(model.x[users,n] for n in model.slots) <= 1

model.OneSlotConstraint = Constraint(model.users, rule=one_slot_rule)

# Certain slots have a minimum balance requirement. 
def min_balance_rule1(model, slots):
    return sum(model.x[n,slots] * model.users_balance[n] for n in 
model.users) >= model.slot_bounds[slots]

model.MinBalanceConstraint1 = Constraint(model.slots, 
rule=min_balance_rule1)
```

So I want to be able to benefit from the fact that I know certain values of x[i,j] to be 0. So for example I have a list of extra conditions

```
x[1,7] = 0
x[3,6] = 0
x[5,8] = 0
```

How do I include this information in order to benefit from reducing the search space? 
Many Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using an abstract model? Are you solving your model using the `pyomo` command or a Python script?

Answer (score 1):

**After** the model is constructed you can do the following:

```
model.x[1,7].fix(0)
model.x[3,6].fix(0)
model.x[5,8].fix(0)
```

or, assuming that you have a Set, model.Arcs, that contains the following:

```
model.Arcs = Set(initialize=[(1,7), (3,6), (5,8)])
```

you can fix x variables in a loop:

```
for i,j in model.Arcs:
    model.x[i,j].fix(0)
```

Comment: Many thanks. Is there a way to do this in a constraint and include the set of (i,j) for which x[i,j]=0 in my .dat file?

Comment: after the model is constructed, does this mean after I have run instance = model.create_instance('mydata.dat')? If I try and run model.x[1,7].fix(0) after I create an instance I get ValueError: Error retrieving component x[1,7]: The component has not been constructed?

Comment: Yes. You need the line `model = model.create_instance('mydata.dat')`

Comment: Yes, you could do this in a constraint using a sparse Param

Comment: Thanks Bethany. I am trying to use spare Param to do this as there are a lot of values to specify. I have `def sparse_rule(model): return model.x[m,n] == 0 for (m,n) in model.Arcs` but this gives me a syntax error. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have defined `Set Arcs: = ...` in mydata.dat file.

Comment: I modified my answer to include this case